# Angular function returned promise before http api completes

Tags: angularjs

I am new in AngularJs.
I have one validate function which is returning promise. this function internally calls http get api and receives promise response. I have some validation code which require the response from the called api. but before http call completes and the function receive response from the api, validate function returned promise to the caller. which is causing validation failed. can someone please share some code which satisfy this requirement.

```
function validateDates(delegate) {      
    var currStartDate = delegate.start_date;
    var currEndDate = delegate.end_date;
    var overlap = false;
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    UserDelegateService.getDelegateForUser(delegate.comit_id).then(
        function(res) {
            for(var i = 0; i<res.length; i++) {
                    var sDate = $filter('date')(res[i].start_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                    var eDate = $filter('date')(res[i].end_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                    if(currStartDate <= eDate && sDate <= currEndDate) {
                        overlap = true;         
                        deferred.resolve(overlap);                          
                    } else
                        deferred.reject("Not overlapping"); 
                }
        },
        function(errorresponse) {
            console.log(errorresponse);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

calling code :

```
$scope.saveDelegate = function() {
    var delegate = {
            //assign values ... 
    };

    var promise = validateDates(delegate);
    promise.then(function(data) {   
        if(data) {
            console.log('Dates are overlapping....if part.......', data);
        }
    }, function(reason) {
            console.log('Dates are not overlapping..saving datlegate..else part.........', reason);
            $scope.save(delegate);
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have done till now ?

Comment: Updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: The correct way to handle this situation is to move the `.then` function to the calling code, or chain another `.then` function behind.  Please show the calling code for suggestions in how this would work.

Comment: Please find updated question

Comment: this code doesn't make a lot of sense.  you are *resolving* the promise when there is an issue and *rejecting* the promise when you want to actually save the values?

Comment: Also the resolve/reject decision gets made on the first item in the list. Subsequent resolve/reject decisions will be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$q.defer` breaks the promise chain and loses error information. Also the resolve/reject decision was being made on first item of the `for` loop.

Instead **return** values and **chain**.

```
function validateDates(delegate) {      
    var currStartDate = delegate.start_date;
    var currEndDate = delegate.end_date;
    //var overlap = false;
    //var deferred = $q.defer();

    var p = UserDelegateService.getDelegateForUser(delegate.comit_id);
    var derivedPromise = p.then(
        function onSuccess(res) {
            //Initialize overlap var in success handler
            var overlap = false; 
            for(var i = 0; i<res.length; i++) {
                var sDate = $filter('date')(res[i].start_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                var eDate = $filter('date')(res[i].end_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                if(currStartDate <= eDate && sDate <= currEndDate) {
                     overlap = true;         
                };
            //Return value of overlap for chaining
            return overlap;
        });
    };
    //return derived promise
    return derivedPromise;
};
```

The above function returns a promise that resolve `true` if any of the dates overlap and resolves `false` if none of the dates overlap.

Client code:

```
$scope.saveDelegate = function() {
    var delegate = {
            //assign values ... 
    };

    var promise = validateDates(delegate);
    promise.then(function onSuccess(overlap) {   
        if(overlap) {
            console.log('Dates are overlapping....if part.......', overlap);
        } else {
            console.log('Dates are not overlapping..saving datlegate..');
            $scope.save(delegate);
        };
    }).catch(function onReject(reason) {
        console.log("Promise rejected for another reason");
    });
};
```

By **returning** and **chaining** promises, any error in the `getDelegateForUser` operation gets forwarded to the client code.